# Calling Activator.CreateInstance from SQLCLR causes exception

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqlclr

I am trying to create a SQL CLR example where depending on the processorClass, represented as a string, I would be able to return the concrete type of the handler to service the request.  When I add the line:

```
MessageProcessorBase messageProcessor = MessageProcessorResolver.Create(MessageProcessorAssemblyName, processorClass);
```

It results in the following Error:

> Msg 6522, Level 16, State 1, Procedure MessageProcessorTrigger, Line 1
>   A .NET Framework error occurred during execution of user-defined routine or aggregate "MessageProcessorTrigger": 
>   System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'MyNamespace.MessageProcessor' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
>   System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 
>      at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
>      at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
>      at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
>      at System.Activator.CreateInstance(String assemblyString, String typeName, Boolean ignoreCase, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes, Evidence securityInfo, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
>      at System.Activator.CreateInstance(String assemblyName, String typeName)
>      at MyNamespace.MessageProcessorFactory.Create(String assemblyName, String handler)
>      at MyNamespace.Triggers.MessageProcessorTrigger()

**Steps**

1. The data is inserted into a table, MessageQueue.
2. A SQL CLR Trigger calls a Create method to get the instance of handler (point of failure).
3. The Handle method on the instance is called.

**Table**

```
CREATE TABLE MessageProcessor.MessageQueue
(
    Id             INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL
,   Name           NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
,   MessageType    INT  NOT NULL
,   StatusId       INT
,   ProcessorClass NVARCHAR(50)
)

ALTER DATABASE MYBD SET TRUSTWORTHY ON;
GO

exec sp_configure 'clr enabled', 1
GO

reconfigure
GO
```

**Trigger (SQL CLR)**

```
public partial class Triggers
{
    private const string MessageProcessorAssemblyName = "MyProcessor.MessageProcessor";
    // Enter existing table or view for the target and uncomment the attribute line
    //[SqlTrigger(Name = "MessageProcessorTrigger", Target = "MessageProcessor.MessageQueue", Event = "FOR INSERT")]
    public static void MessageProcessorTrigger()
    {
        SqlTriggerContext triggerContext = SqlContext.TriggerContext;
        string processorClass = string.Empty;

        if (triggerContext == null) return;
        if (triggerContext.TriggerAction == TriggerAction.Insert)
        {
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(" context connection=true"))
            {
                conn.Open();
                SqlCommand command = conn.CreateCommand();
                SqlPipe sqlP = SqlContext.Pipe;

                command.Connection = conn;
                command.CommandText = "SELECT ProcessorClass FROM INSERTED";

                processorClass = command.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
                sqlP.Send(string.Format("Called MessageProcessor {0}", processorClass));

                //var handle = Activator.CreateInstance(MessageProcessorAssemblyName, processorClass);

                MessageProcessorBase messageProcessor = MessageProcessorFactory.Create(MessageProcessorAssemblyName,
                    processorClass);
                messageProcessor.HandleMessage(string.Empty);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And finally the call to Resolver to obtain the instance on which to call the Handle Method.

```
public class MessageProcessorResolver
{
    public static MessageProcessorBase Create(string assemblyName, string handler)
    {
        return (MessageProcessorBase)Activator.CreateInstance(assemblyName, handler).Unwrap();
    }
}
```

I create the Assembly with Permission Set UNSAFE, just to enable event logging as this is currently the only operation the handler carries out.
It seems to be the call to Activator.CreateInstance where the issue begins, as when I set the return type to be CustomerMessageHandler in the Create method everything works as expected.  I know using Reflection is not permitted in SQLCLR, and the error seems to be pointing in this direction, but I have seen examples of this being used [here](https://github.com/ryan1234/sqlclr/blob/master/POC/Builder.cs), which led me to thinking maybe I am just missing something.

For completeness the MessageProcessorBase is simply an abstract class with a single method, Handle

```
public abstract class MessageProcessorBase
{
    public virtual void HandleMessage(string messageDetails)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Handled by Message Processor Base Method");
    }
}
```

and the CustomerMessageHandler is simply:

```
public class CustomerMessageHandler : MessageProcessorBase
{
    public override void HandleMessage(string messageDetails)
    {
        const string source = "Message Processor SQLCLR";
        const string log = "Application";
        const string logEvent = "Customer Processor";

        if (!EventLog.SourceExists(source))
            EventLog.CreateEventSource(source, log);

        EventLog.WriteEntry(source, logEvent);
        Console.WriteLine("Handled by Customer Handler");
    }
}
```

Please excuse the length of this post, I have tried to be as complete as possible.

Comment: Just realised the title should have added "Not Working"

Comment: Loading any assembly under any conditions is not permitted in sqlclr, from the exception I can see that an assembly load attempt has been made. Check this link thoroughly, this might help. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlclr/2006/10/18/dynamic-assembly-loading/ and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms403273.aspx , the code in github though uses Activator.CreateInstance but are you sure it works.